# How to cut characters only from lines beginning with x?

Tags: linux, unix, grep, cut

I'm trying to cut everything between the 2nd and 18th character using `cut -c-2-18- filename`. This cuts specified characters on every line but I'd like to cut it only from lines beginning with `>`.

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
grep ^\> file | cut -c 2-18
```

Should do the trick?

```
[92][11:46:21] vlazarenko@alluminium (~/tests) > grep ^\> file | cut -c 2-18
 asdf
 bcda
 ofpjg
[93][11:46:25] vlazarenko@alluminium (~/tests) > cat file
> asdf
> bcda
zxcv
lasdf
> ofpjg
```

Comment: @sudo-o: original way of adding alternatives ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can you do this with `GNU grep` alone:

```bsh
$ cat file
>grep from 2 to 18 character line 1
>grep from 2 to 18 character line 2
grep from 2 to 18 character line 3
grep from 2 to 18 character line 4

$ grep -Po '(?<=^>).{17}' file
grep from 2 to 18
grep from 2 to 18
```

This uses [positive lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to only match lines starting with `>` and `.{17}` matches the next 17 characters.

Or with `awk`:

```bsh
$ awk '/^>/{print substr($0,2,18)}' file
grep from 2 to 18 
grep from 2 to 18
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '/^\>/{print substr($0,2,17)}' your_file
```